# Scenekit: recolor diffuse texture with shader

Tags: ios, shader, scenekit, scnmaterial

I want to write some shader (surface/fragment/...) to recolor my diffuse texture in some new color. Currently I have this version of shader (I'm trying to recolor texture in real time):

```
//sm_surf

uniform vec4 colorTarget; (used in full version)
uniform vec4 colorTint; (used in full version)

vec4 colorTexture = texture2D(u_diffuseTexture, _surface.diffuseTexcoord);
//vec4 colorTexture = _sample.diffuse;//the same result

vec4 tinted = colorTexture;
tinted.r = max(0.0, colorTexture.r - 0.2);
_surface.diffuse = tinted;
```

And this is the code in OpenCV (I just recolored texture beforehand and used it as new diffuse texture):

```
image = cv::imread([path UTF8String], cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
for (int i = 0; i < image.rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < image.cols; j++) {
        cv::Vec4b pixel = image.at<cv::Vec4b>(i,j);
        pixel[2] = fmin(255, fmax(0, pixel[2] - 50));
        image.at<cv::Vec4b>(i,j) = pixel;
    }
}

cv::imwrite([newPath UTF8String], image);
```

For this test I just want to reduce R component of color.
Results:

OpenCV (**correct**)

[image: opencv image]

SceneKit (**incorrect**)

[image: SceneKit image]

diffuse texture contains alpha channel.

**(SOLVED by mnuages)**
Also, seems like after recoloring shader alpha channel is broken. With this shader:

```
tinted.r = 1;
tinted.g = 0;
tinted.b = 0;
```

My result is:[image: scenekit]

instead of:[image: opencv]

Original texture: [image: original]

How can I just recolor diffuse texture like in openCV?

---

**UPDATE:**
This are result for SceneKit shader and OpenCV (I have removed all transparent pixels from image):

OpenCV:
[image: openCV]

SceneKit:
[image: SceneKit]

shader:

```
vec4 colorTexture = _surface.diffuse;
vec3 tinted = colorTexture.a > 0.0 ? colorTexture.rgb / colorTexture.a : colorTexture.rgb;
if (colorTexture.a == 1) {
    tinted.r = max(0.0, colorTexture.r - 0.2);
} else {
    colorTexture.a = 0;
}
_surface.diffuse = vec4(tinted, 1.0) * colorTexture.a;
```

and OpenCV code:

```
pixel[2] = fmax(0, pixel[2] - 50);//2 because it's bgr in OpenCV
if (pixel[3] != 255) {
    pixel[3] = 0;
}
```

---

Some more strange things:
I have changed my OpenCV code to this to generate new texture

```
pixel[0] = 255 - (j % 4) * 30;//b
pixel[1] = 0;//g
pixel[2] = 0;//r
pixel[3] = 255;
```

If I change this texture like this:

```
if (pixel[0] == 255) {
    pixel[0] = 255;pixel[1] = 255;pixel[2] = 255;
} else {
    pixel[0] = 0;pixel[1] = 0;pixel[2] = 0;
}
```

I receive smth like this:

[image: opencv]

With this SceneKit shader it should be the same:

```
vec4 colorTexture = _surface.diffuse;
vec3 tinted = colorTexture.rgb; // colorTexture.a == 1
if (tinted.b > 0.99) {
    tinted = vec3(0,0,0);
} else {
    tinted = vec3(1,1,1);
}
_surface.diffuse = vec4(tinted, 1.0) * colorTexture.a;
```

But I receive this:

[image]

There are some white stripes, but way too thin.

I can increase them by changing condition to tinted.b > 0.85, but it's already an error, because color in _surface.diffuse not the same as in texture. Seems like SceneKit interpolates the texture or smth like that.

---

**UPDATE2:**

I have added [source code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WPLhlXEzrr9o3L-R0VO_E3UNQpotCcIL/view?usp=sharing) (1.5Mb) with this problem. There are 3 spheres:

1 Top) With original texture

2 Left) With texture recolored by shader (newR = r - 0.2) (float)

3 Right) With texture recolored by OpenCV (newR = r - 51) (uint8)

and they are different! Scene doesn't contain any light/env/... just 3 spheres.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SceneKit uses premultiplied alpha. The following should work:

```
vec3 tinted = colorTexture.a > 0.f ? colorTexture.rgb / colorTexture.a : colorTexture.rgb;
tinted.r = max(0.0, tinted.r - 0.2);
_surface.diffuse = vec4(tinted, 1.f) * colorTexture.a;
```

---

**Edit**

This code works well in the example you attached, but requires some changes for the two techniques to match 100%. As explained in [this other SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44045637/2997825), SceneKit shaders operate in a linear color space.

This means that `51` in your CPU code doesn't map to `0.2` in your GPU code.
To get the same result you will need to convert the sampled color (linear) to a tinted color (non-linear), apply the tint operation, and then convert back to linear.

---

As for the example with stripes, this is the expected behaviour. [Mipmapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap) will lead to grayscale values. If you move close enough to the object so that 1 texel is projected onto ~1 pixel on screen, then you'll only get black and white values again.

Comment: Thanks! You helped me with "alpha channel" problem. In my previous fix for this problem I used **tinted** for 3 textures - diffuse, emission and transparent. Color was almost the same, but your solutions much better;) Can you help me with first problem? Seems like color in colorTexture not the same as in original texture. Something like interpolated...

Comment: I have updated my question with more test and information.

Comment: I modified my answer. Should be `max(0.0, tinted.r - 0.2);` and not `max(0.0, colorTexture.r - 0.2);`

Comment: I added source code with this problem. There is no alphaChannel/Light/EnvLight/... and still this problem exists. Please take a look at it

Comment: I edited my answer. Everything works well except a small change with regard to color spaces to perfectly match the desired look.

Comment: Thank you! This is just what I needed to know.

Comment: Thanks this saved my day. I have been trying to solve the problem of removing specific tone of green from our videos for days. Scenekit surface shader color inputs didn't match the values we expect and this was the problem we need to divide the colors to alpha.