# Why is ARSCNView.snapshot() output different from ARFrame.capturedImage?

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I created a view with the two Image Views side-by-side to compare the two.

Left side is from [`ARFrame.capturedImage`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arframe/2867984-capturedimage).

Right side is from [`ARSCNView.snapshot()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnview/1524031-snapshot)

You can see that the left side is slightly brighter than the right side, even though I pointed the camera at a white wall.

[image: White wall]

I need both functions to return the same pixel values for the same object, so that I can later copy over certain pixels without obvious contours showing up due to the difference in brightness.

Is it perhaps due to how I am converting the `CVPixelFrameBuffer` into `UIImage`?

Comment: I don’t think the brightness is the problem. Take a closer look at the wrinkles in the bottom they are different pictures. I think the right one is zoomed

Comment: @sj-r I've replaced the image with the camera pointed at a white wall. The misalignment in the wrinkles may just have been due to capture lag between the two photos.

Comment: I believe the reason is because ARKit uses gamma sRGB, whereas SceneKit uses linear sRGB. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44033605/why-is-metal-shader-gradient-lighter-as-a-scnprogram-applied-to-a-scenekit-node/44045637#44045637
However, there seems to be no fast way to do the conversion without diving into shader code.

Comment: Nevermind, I implemented the conversion but it's still off :(