# Render an SCNGeometry - the output color in fragment shader modifiers not the final color to display

Tags: fragment, shader, scenekit, arkit, modifier

I'm using SceneKit and ARKit on iOS and I have a face geometry and want to change it's color.

but I found the _output.color is not the final color to display. For Example, a fragment shader modifier is like this:

```
_output.color.rgba = float4(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
```

the face color to display should be RGB(127, 127, 127), but the fact is RGB(188, 188, 188).

I don't know why this happened, Can anybody tell me the reason and introduce the workflow of the geometry shaders. Thanks

Comment: This is because SceneKit doesn't render in the sRGB color space, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44045637/2997825

Comment: thank you for replay, i have fixed it by your advice